# Can I use a constant for partition key and unique sort key in Dynamodb?

Tags: key, amazon-dynamodb, partition

I have Apartment table and want to get document by apart number and list by building number, which I can achive by using "begin_with"

For example, lets say there are apartment units from 101 to 105 in building 1, and 201 to 205 in building 2.
Here's the table Im thinking may look like..
PK - "APART" (constant)
SK - 101

So I can query by pk-apart, sk- begin with 1 for query building 1

Im newbie dynamodb and nosql so please advise if it's possible and if possible, is it bad practice?
Could you please also explain why?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, but I would not recommend it. You will end up with a hot partition once you start putting a lot of data in the database. If you know the database will never exceed about 10,000 entries and you're not going to have more than a 50 or so RCUs/WCUs, you could probably get away with it.